# Structuring Class with constructor

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a Class with a Constructor. My constructor takses all the required parameter, then I use the parameters to return another class.

```
Public Class SearchResults()

  private id as int


    Sub New(id) ' Constructor
        getResults(id)
    End Sub

    Public Function getResults(byval id as int) as List(of Products)
       ........
      return list (of products)
    End Function

End
```

Then in my page I want to get all the productts.

```
Dim s = new SearchResults( 1 )
Dim p as list(of Products) = s.getResults()
```

----now I can do for Each on this

This works for me, but I do have a feeling there has to be a better way of doing it, I want to stick to the best standards. do you guys think, this is the best approach or it could be improved? My designers will be utilizing this class within their projects...so i would love to make it as simple as possible for them.

**or maybe how to create an Collection of a Class...for example Class Product and its collection Class Products, Where Products is the Collection of Project Class.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do what you want:
1) You can load the results and store them in the object on the constructor
2) You can store the ID in the object and call the function to get the results when needed
3) You can make the function static and pass in the ID as well as the collection (or resource needed to get the collection) and not use an object at all.

Depending on what you need, most likely either 1 or 3 are going to be best. If you plan on reusing the object for other methods than just the one function, then option 1 is the best, but if you just need the 1 function, go with option 3 like this:

```
Public Class SearchResults
Public Static Function getResults(ByVal id As int) As List(Of Products)
   '........
  return list (of products)
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I can make it Static, but in real application I have to pass around 10 parameters, I was thinking to either pass those parameters as Constructor parameter's or in class create Properties for every paramater, what do you think?

Comment: Pass the parameters into the constructor. If they aren't going to change you only need to create get; properties. At this point its a matter of preference, and I could certainly argue my way, but either way is acceptable when it comes to properties for /most/ applications. For maximum security you want to minimize properties with set; accessors when there is no need for an external object or process to modify that variable.

Comment: So....    Dim p as List(of product) =  Searchresults(a,b,c,s).getResutls is way to go (Where getResults is a Static Method?

Comment: How are you getting the results? If its from a resource such as Sql Server then the one thing you need to change is passing the connection into the function: Searchresults (parmA, parmB, parmC, sOpenConnection)

You will have thread safety problems if you try to access a resource such as SqlServer through a static function.

Comment: getResults() within class will connecti to SQL and returns the Records.

Comment: OK, then no, don't use a static function. Instead, pass the parameters into the constructor and then have the constructor save the results to the Object. You can then access the results through properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the getResults method static possibly and cut out having to create a class instance to call it.

Comment: or maybe how to create an Collection of a Class...for example Class Product and its collection Class Products, Where Products is the Collection of Project Class.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would declare the `getResults` method as `Shared` so that you don't have to create a `SearchResults` object just to access that method. This would also allow you to call the method again with another ID without having to create another object.

Comment: in that case Constructor has be Shared as well? or it does not matter?

Comment: @highwingers ~ it shouldn't matter b/c it won't be called.